# Why does my localStorage PET value becomes empty string when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

My localStorage PET value becomes empty string everytime I refresh the page. I'm using React and typescript SWC (Vite). I'm stuck and don't know what's wrong. Please help thank you!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import petImage from "./assets/kungfudie.gif";

function App(): JSX.Element {
    const [petName, setPetName] = useState<string>("");

    //get data from localStorage on every render
    useEffect(() => {
        const name = localStorage.getItem("PET");
        if (name) {
            setPetName(JSON.parse(name));
        }
    }, []);

    //set localStorage when petName change
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("PET", JSON.stringify(petName));
    }, [petName]);

    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-900 text-gray-100 text-center p-5">
            <h1 className="mb-5">My Pet</h1>
            <input
                placeholder="Set Pet Name"
                value={petName}
                type="text"
                name="petName"
                id="petName"
                onChange={(e) => setPetName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <h1 className="my-5">
                {petName.length > 0 ? `Hi I'm ${petName}` : "Give me a name"}
            </h1>
            <div>
                <img style={{ maxWidth: 500 }} src={petImage} alt="Pet Image" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason localStorage `PET` value becomes an empty string every time you refresh the page, is that on the first render `petName` initializes as an empty string:

```
const [petName, setPetName] = useState<string>("");
```

Then, as soon as the component is mounted you're getting value from `localStorage` (if there is some), and set it to the `petName` variable using the `setPetName` function:

```
 //get data from localStorage on every render
  useEffect(() => {
    const name = localStorage.getItem('PET')
    if (name) {
      setPetName(JSON.parse(name))
    }
  }, [])
```

After that, you declare another `useEffect` hook that fires every time `petName` variable changes:

```
//set localStorage when petName change
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('PET', JSON.stringify(petName))
  }, [petName])
```

And this is the hook that sets `PET` as an empty string to `localStorage` on the first render.
The reason is that, on the first render, by the time React fires this hook, value of `petName` variable is still an empty string, as React hadn't applied updates to `petName` that were made inside the previous hook:

```
//get data from localStorage on every render
  useEffect(() => {
    const name = localStorage.getItem('PET')
    if (name) {
      setPetName(JSON.parse(name))
    }
  }, [])
```

To prevent this buggy behavior, and to initialize `petName` using value from `localStorage` on the first render, you need to:

1. Delete this `useEffect` hook:

```
 //get data from localStorage on every render
 useEffect(() => {
   const name = localStorage.getItem('PET')
   if (name) {
     setPetName(JSON.parse(name))
   }
 }, [])
```

2. Move initialization from `localStorage` to `useState`, using function, that returns a value

```
const [petName, setPetName] = useState<string>(
   () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('PET')) || ''
 )
```

Comment: thank you, you save me hours of debugging.